# How to Connect a System that has only JSON input and output with another that has XML input and output

Tags: xml, json

Let's assume there are two systems (A and B) that need to send data files back and forth, however both have been engineered independently and one supports JSON only, while the other supports XML only.

What are potential solutions to enable them connect?

System A, which deals with JSON only files cannot be altered. System B, which deals with XML only files potentially could be altered, but only as a last resort, and at great cost.

On a high level, I'd anticipate that something sits between, which does some format conversion. What forms could this intermediary take, what are the pros and cons of these options, considering security, reliability, ease of deployment and performance impact.

All relevant views welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are many libraries that do that. If you're e.g. programming C#, there's `JSON.NET`, a library that [can do that for you](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/ConvertingJSONandXML.htm) but there are [libraries for just about every imaginable language](http://json.org/), due to its popularity.

From a design point of view, `XML` and `JSON` are two formats that are typically used in web services and they, in turn are typically used for inter-machine communication. To allow for two-way conversion, each web service would have a method that can convert from A to B.

As you'll read on json.org, there's really no reason to churn out your own conversion code, unless you really want to.

In terms of ease of use, as I said, web services are the *de facto* standard for this kind of serialized inter-machine communication and are pretty straight-forward. Performance and security are of course web- or network-related and you should look into what the data volumes and project requirements are before you jump to conclusions.